# convert date and time string to POSIX in R

Tags: r

I have a date and time as this:

```
"2013-09-05 0:00am"
```

I need to convert this to POSIX and I tried this:

```
as.POSIXct(c("2013-09-01 0:00am"), format="%Y-%m-%d %I:%M%p")
```

I am getting an NA output, any ideas why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because there's no such thing as "00:00 AM".  If you're using an AM/PM indicator, then the only possible values for hours are 1-12.  If you want to use hours 00-24, then you can't use an AM/PM indicator.

Comment: I used gsub to change 0:00am to 12:00am and then did this: as.POSIXct(c("2013-09-01 12:00am"), format="%Y-%m-%d %I:%M%p",tz="America/New_York"), still no luck

Comment: Works for me. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no 0:00am.
Try

```
 as.POSIXct(c("2013-09-01 1:00am"), format="%Y-%m-%d %I:%M%p",tz="America/New_York")
```

and it works.

Comment: Hmm... 12:00am corresponds to 00:00 and is, as it seems, not displayed by default. Try `format(as.POSIXct(c("2013-09-01 12:00am"), format="%Y-%m-%d %I:%M%p",tz="America/New_York"),format="%Y-%m-%d %I:%M%p")` and 12:00am is displayed.