# How can i convert my column(character) to POSIXct to create time series?

Tags: r

I want to convert my `PM10` `dataframe` to `xts` format by using `R ;` but the type of the first column(`date`) is character. Therefore, firstly, I need to convert it to `POSIXct;` but whenever I tried, it runs to NA.

My dates are like this: `2014-01-01 00:00`

I tried this code and it didn't work. How can I make it work?

```
date_index  <- as.POSIXct(bes_yillik[,1],tz ="UTC",format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: The date format that you describe (2014-01-01 00:00) corresponds tp `format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"`. Does this solve the issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert date and time string to POSIX in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18874400/convert-date-and-time-string-to-posix-in-r)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use `anytime` without the need for specifying the `format`

```
library(anytime)   
anytime("2014-01-01 00:00")
bes_yillik$timefield <- anytime(bes_yillik$timefield)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `lubridate` package for datetime stuff:

```
lubridate::ymd_hm("2014-01-01 00:00")
[1] "2014-01-01 UTC"

bes_yillik$timefield <- lubridate::ymd_hm(bes_yillik$timefield)
```

Comment: Thank you Sonny. I tried this code, but it gived error. Maybe it can be related to my data. Then, I tried "anytime" and it worked.